# PhotoKit - get thumbnail image and video data

Tags: swift, photokit

I'd like to make a list view of videos which saved in user's Photos App.
So, I'm trying to make an array containing thumbnail image and AVAsset(or duration and fileURL).

But in the following code, I'm wondering if I can't make the array because of the multiple blocks.
The reason I wrote to blocks was I wanted to get both the thumbnail image and the video data(duration and fileURL).

Is there a way to make such an array?

PhotoKit Fetch Request

```
var videos = [Video]()

let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()

let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
let imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()

let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
fetchResult.enumerateObjects { (phAsset, _, _) in
    var video = Video()
    imageManager.requestImage(for: phAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: imageRequestOptions) { (uiImage, _) in
        video.thumbnailImage = uiImage!
        self.videos.append(video)
    }
    imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: nil) { (avAsset, _, _) in
        if avAsset != nil {
            video.asset = avAsset!
        }
    }
}
```

Array's Element

```
struct Video {
    var thumbnailImage: UIImage?
    var asset: AVAsset?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just nest the calls:

```
var video = Video()
imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: nil) { (avAsset, _, _) in
    if avAsset != nil {
        video.asset = avAsset!
    }
    imageManager.requestImage(for: phAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: imageRequestOptions) { (uiImage, _) in
        video.thumbnailImage = uiImage!
        self.videos.append(video)
    }
}
```